# SQL Server TRIGGER UPDATE on change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to do a TRIGGER UPDATE for a web store and I want the total amount (`col2`) to update every time something is added into the order, all orders are done in one table (`table1`) and then all the orders are stored in another table (`table2`). I keep getting errors with `table1.col1 = table2.col1` where `col1` is an ID.

```
CREATE TRIGGER table2.col2
ON table1
FOR UPDATE
BEGIN
    UPDATE table2
    SET newTable =
        (SELECT table2.col2 AS p
        FROM table2
        JOIN inserted AS i
        ON p.orderId = i.orderId)
    WHERE table2.orderId = table1.orderId
END
```

Comment: Why is your trigger not referencing the `inserted` or `deleted` objects?

Comment: I thought the `SELECT` referenced them

Comment: Your select references table2 and table1 - no mention of `Inserted`

Comment: [Using Inserted and DEleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The obvious issue with your update is `WHERE table1.col1 = table2.col1` you can't access table1 in your where clause if its not the table being updated or joined to it.

Comment: I edited the code to add `insterted` and hopefully fix `WHERE`

Comment: You're still trying to reference table1 in your where clause, but table1 only exists inside the sub-query so isn't available to the update statement.

Comment: Why doesn't it reference `table1` for the whole thing when it is being mentioned at `ON table1`?

Comment: That only tells SQL Server what object to associate the trigger with. You are then provided with `Inserted` and `Deleted` which you can use to do what you like with, but you have to write your SQL as your would outside a trigger, specifying all the tables etc.

Comment: If I added a `FROM table1` after `UPDATE table2` would it work? I fell like it wouldn't but I don't really know how I would do it.

Comment: Consider the problem, you want to update table2, and you want to update all the rows that correspond to a row being updated in table1. The answer I have given does exactly that. I'm not sure why you want to do it differently?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably re-write it without a sub-query but the quick fix is to add `inserted` into your `where` clause as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table2.col2
ON table1
FOR UPDATE
BEGIN
    UPDATE table2 SET
        newTable = (
            SELECT table2.col2 AS p
            FROM table2
            JOIN inserted AS i
            ON p.orderId = i.orderId
        )
    WHERE table2.orderId in (select orderId from Inserted)
END
```

`Inserted` is a pseudo table which contains a row with the new data (aside from large columns) for each row being updated.

Comment: Does `Inserted` reference what is at `ON table1`?

Comment: @RodrigoL did you read the reference link I provided on the Inserted and Deleted pseudo-tables?

Comment: Yeah, just having a bit of trouble understanding it, it creates a copy of the rows while it runs the `UPDATE`. I just don't get how `in (select orderId from Inserted)` would fix the referencing problem.

Comment: `(select orderid from Inserted)` gives you a list of IDs being updated, so you pull the same rows from the actual table to do an actual update. My logic may be incorrect because I don't fully understand what you are doing but it appears to match what you posted.